# Change data in ng-repeat when another data is created

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have data (Games) , and ng-repeat this data on HTML.

```
<div ng-controller="parent">
   <div ng-repeat="game in Games track by $index">...</div> 
   ...
</div>
```

On another child controller (ng-controller="child") user can collect his favorites games ,from 'Games', in another data 'favGames' ,and create his own games list.

How can i check , if user select some games , then switch Games to favGames , and show favGames data on   ng-controller="parent" .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: watcha got so far? what version of angular? what does your data structure look like?

Comment: @alphapilgrim , angular 1.6 , data structure is the same both of controllers

Comment: I get data from child controller ,try to pass it to parent. But it works only at once , so , maybe i need to write $watch in child controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement that in 2 ways :

**1/ Watchers on your parent controller**

Create a `$rootScope.favGames` and watch it in your parent controller.
Upon change; edit your `$scope.games = $rootScope.favGamers`

**2/ Broadcast :** Cleaner solution

Upon change on favGames; $broadcast the change

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('$favGames.updated', {
    games: favFames
});
```

In your parent controller catch the change :

```
$scope.$on('$favGames.updated', function(events, data) {
    $scope.games = data.games
});
```

Comment: I prefer second way , and it works fantastic !
Thanks men, you are a hero :)